# Remove shortcut made from installed shield using wix installer

Tags: wix, installshield

I would like to delete  shortcuts that was made by installed shield. I am now using wix installer and need to delete the old shortcuts. I DO NOT want to uninstalled the old one. I just need to remove the shortcuts

Comment: Make a script, and tell Wix to run it after install. Sadly WIX is not very flexible... i end up building my own release exe using a small C# program I built as it is more flexible...

Answer (score 2):

Shortcuts are just files so you can use [`RemoveFile`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefile.html) to delete shortcuts.

Comment: This is not true for wix.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the project you're upgrading is a Basic MSI, both the old and new versions are subject to the rules of Windows Installer, so be careful not to violate any [component rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367849.aspx) that will [cause you problems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372795.aspx).

If the shortcut is part of a component whose contents you can completely remove, consider matching its contents in your wix project, marking it Transitive, and giving it a false condition.